# What is a proper way to switch between two views of json?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have source_json data looking like this:

```
{
  'ID': {
    '0': 8573273,
    '1': 8573277
  },
  'prediction': {
    '0': 4.411029362081518,
    '1': 4.411029362081518
  },
  'feature': {
    '0': 0,
    '1': 0
  }
}
```

But I need it to be in this form:

```
[
  {
    'ID': 8573273,
    'prediction': 4.411029362081518,
    'feature': 0
  },
  {
    'ID': 8573277,
    'prediction': 4.411029362081518,
    'feature': 0
  }
]
```

I convert the first view to Pandas dataframe and then convert it to the desirable json.

```
t = pd.DataFrame(source_json)
proper_jsone = t.to_dict(orient='records')
```

**The question** is: Is there a  proper way to do this without creating an additional dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer traditional way:

```py
all_keys = list(source_json.keys())
all_indices = list(source_json[all_keys[0]].keys())
transformed_json = [ {_k:source_json[_k][_idx] for _k in all_keys} for _idx in all_indices]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I mark your answer because it's more scalable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try list comprehension

```py
[{'ID':i, 'prediction':j, 'feature':k} 
    for i,j,k in zip(*[i.values() for i in d.values()]) ]
```

output

```
[{'ID': 8573273, 'prediction': 4.411029362081518, 'feature': 0},
 {'ID': 8573277, 'prediction': 4.411029362081518, 'feature': 0}]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I accepted Mont as answer because his solution is more scalable.